# GroupBox autosize

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize, groupbox

Take a `GroupBox`, put let say `Label` inside and then set `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink` and `AutoSize = true`.

Two problems will arise:

- There is a huge gap between `Label` and bottom of `GroupBox` (almost enough to fit another `Label` lol);
- `AutoSize` doesn't respect the `GroupBox.Text` property.

Question is **how to make `GroupBox.AutoSize` working properly**? Properly means: minimum Width should be enough to fit `GroupBox.Text`, there should be no gaps below for unknown reason (it's not `Margin`, nor `Padding` and it looks pretty ugly).

---

I've tried to measure string length in `OnPaint` and setting `MinimumSize` right there. It works, but I have doubts about this, as if I would want to actually set `MinimumSize` later - it will be lost after repaint.

---

Update, here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's obviously that the `label1` Location is not `Point(0,0)`? You didn't even try my solution.

Comment: Yes i tried, and no it doesn't work. I told this in the answer itself. Want me to post another screenshot where `GroupBox` is collapsed (because nothing then prevent `AutoSize` from reducing size of parent to zero). Tell me please, what should I do now with this question? I have an issue, obvious, unsolved, coming from Microsoft, but my question is on hold, so no one will ever bother to answer on it. Re-post it again?

Answer (score 5):

You can get rid of the unwanted yellow space at the bottom by deriving a new class from GroupBox that adjusts the bottom edge a bit. In VB something like ...

```
Public Class BetterGroupBox
    Inherits GroupBox

    Public Overrides Function GetPreferredSize(ByVal proposedSize As Size) As Size
        Dim ns = MyBase.GetPreferredSize(proposedSize)
        Return New Size(ns.Width, ns.Height - 15)
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple that the location of your `Label` is fixed at some point other than `(0,0)`, try this:

```
label1.Location = Point.Empty;
```

You may also want to try setting the `Padding` of your `GroupBox` to `0` for all (default is 3):

```
groupBox1.Padding = new Padding(0);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Setting this and then `GroupBox.AutoSize = true` will collapse group box to have 1 pixel width or something. Interesting enough, the **height** of collapsed group box will same bigger than needed (to fit ~one more `Label` under `label1`). How this answer suppose to fix second issue (with `GroupBox.Text`) ?

Comment: @Sinatr please post your screen shot. I've tried with this and it `shrinks`  almost to the size of the inner `Label`.

Comment: @Sinatr the size is resized depending on the text of `GroupBox`, isn't that better?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the `GroupBox` control has a predefined padding of sorts when growing the control if `AutoSize = true`.  That is, once a control (inside the GroupBox) gets within 20 pixels or so of the bottom of the GroupBox, the GroupBox starts growing.  This causes a 20 pixel or so padding from the bottom of the bottom-most control to the bottom of the GroupBox (as highlighted in yellow by @Sinatr's attached image).

Based on my observations, the padding seems to be less when growing the `Width` of the GroupBox.

At any rate, you can do something like the following "get around" the issue:

```
    public void MyFunction()
    {
        groupBox1.AutoSize = true;

        // Do stuff (e.g., add controls to GroupBox)...

        // Once all controls have been added to the GroupBox...
        groupBox1.AutoSize = false;

        // Add optional padding here if desired.
        groupBox1.Height = myBottomMostControl.Bottom;
    }
```