# GroupBox.AutoSize and GroupBox.Text wrapping

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize, groupbox

I have two problems with the `GroupBox`, they appears after setting `GroupBox.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink` and `GroupBox.AutoSize = true`.

[image: GrouBox bug]

- `GroupBox.Text` width is not taken into account at all. Sizing will occurs to fit content only and then text will get wrapped if it doesn't fit. If it cannot fit - it is simply not displayed.
- There is unnecessarily big gap between bottom of the `GroupBox` and `Label` inside.

### Questions:

How to make `GroupBox` respecting its `Text` property when autosizing? And how to remove that gap?

---

For some reasons my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308883/groupbox-autosize) question gets on hold. Should I delete it or what?

P.S.: if you are putting on hold or something, please comment what is exactly not-clear in what I am asking!

Comment: the `GroupBox` is designed to autosize accordingly to its children(child controls), not its `Text`.

Comment: .. and there is no way to deal with it? Currently I have to make own control (based on `GroupBox`), draw everything, but I have difficulty to deal with build-in `AutoSize` and none of my solutions satisfy me: calculating size in `OnPaint` and setting `MinimumSize`, using parent container/form `OnVisibleChanged` event to set `MinimumSize` again, using not-autosized GroupBox, but size it manually. I want to have nice automatically working control, yet can not understand how to deal with that *gap-bug*.

Comment: @Sinatr we all want that, but that's not going to happen. try registrating the resize event maybe and undo it or stop the resize

Comment: Maybe you can use a LayoutPanel in your groupbox?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName, so I shouldn't use `AutoSize` and rather manually set size based on content? Wierd... @CristisS, it doesn't matter what is inside, the `GroupBox` will keep *gap* between *that* and bottom line for unknown reasons.

Comment: You can't escape the wpf trolls here.  You might have better luck at the MSDN forums, they have a dedicated forum for winforms questions.

Comment: @HighCore, WPF is out of the question yet. I do like stackoverflow more than MSDN and most of answers to my problems I find/get here. Seems to be uncommon issue, then.. I'll just wait for someone with the similar issue..

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
Calculate the Text Width in pixels, then set the size for the GroupBox.
*/


groupBoxA.SuspendLayout();


SizeF stringSizeLabel;

using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
{
    Font stringFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F);
    stringSizeLabel = graphics.MeasureString("SAMPLE TEXT", stringFont);
}

int iWidth = (int)(stringSizeLabel.Width * 1.35f); // Give a little extra width
int iHeight = 78; // This is a sample value

groupBoxA.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(iWidth, iHeight);
groupBoxA.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(iWidth, iHeight);


groupBoxA.ResumeLayout(false);
groupBoxA.PerformLayout();
```